# Why does BOM cause warning "headers have already been sent"?

Tags: php, warnings, configuration-files, byte-order-mark

Please note this is not a duplicate. The seeming duplicates can all be answered by "Just save without a BOM already!" My question, however, is why?

If I save a PHP file inadvertently with a BOM, and I try to sent a header from inside the PHP, I get

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at file.php:1) in **file.php** on line **1**

You know the routine. And of course, it doesn't happen when the file is saved without a BOM.

However, and here's the tricky part: this warning does not occur everywhere! In my case, it doesn't occur when I open up the file from `http://localhost/`, but it does occur when I upload the file to my website, and open it from there.

So, what's the difference? Is there a bug either my local Apache, or the website's Apache? Would the issue be solved by upgrading the buggy one to the latest version? Or could it be a configuration issue somewhere, that could be resolved by editing an ini file?

Comment: Because BOM is output, so it causes the headers to be sent. The difference is possibly an error_reporting configuration difference.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your local host has the [implicit output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) turned on.

Also, [detect_unicode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.detect-unicode) might be worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My php.ini did have `output_buffering = 4096` and I changed that to `Off` and restarted Apache, but that didn't make a difference. Nor did changing `delect_unicode` and `zend.multibyte` have any effect. So I didn't get any further.